# How to transfer variable from python file to python flask

Tags: python, flask, trello

I want to transfer label_count and card_m to my main flask python file. How do I do that? I already tried importing it it didn't work. And if there is any solution to card_m I don't want repeat request so many times

```
import requests
import json
from itertools import chain 
from collections import Counter
  
url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/OIeEN1vG/cards"
query = {
    'key': 'e8cac9f95a86819d54194324e95d4db8',
    'token': 'aee28b52f9f8486297d8656c82a467bb4991a1099e23db539604ac35954d5633'
    }

response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    params=query
    )
data = response.json()
card_labels_string = list(chain.from_iterable([d['labels']for d in data]))
card_labels = [c ["color"] for c in card_labels_string]
label_count = dict((i, card_labels.count(i)) for i in card_labels)

cards = dict(zip([d['name']for d in data],[d['shortLink']for d in data]))
card_m = {}
for key,value in cards.items():
    url_card = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{}/members".format(value)
    res = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url_card,
        params=query
        )
    names = [f['fullName']for f in res.json()]
    card_m.update({key : names})

print(label_count, card_m)
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by transfer. How are you going to be using label_count and card_m? Answer those two and I might be able to help out. But I don't know what situation you are trying to accomplish so i can't help.

Comment: I mean I want to get card_m and label_count values from this python file and print it on my HTML  file through flask app python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on you comments i think i can help you out now. So two things you should do to make this as clean as possible and to avoid bugs later on.

Right now your code is in the global scope. You should avoid doing this at cost unless there is literally no other option. So first thing you should do is create a static class for holding this data. Maybe something like this.

```
class LabelHelper(object):
    card_m = {}
    label_count = None

    @classmethod
    def startup(cls):
        url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/OIeEN1vG/cards"
        query = {
            'key': 'e8cac9f95a86819d54194324e95d4db8',
            'token': 'aee28b52f9f8486297d8656c82a467bb4991a1099e23db539604ac35954d5633'
        }

        response = requests.request(
            "GET",
            url,
            params=query
        )
        data = response.json()
        card_labels_string = list(chain.from_iterable([d['labels'] for d in data]))
        card_labels = [c["color"] for c in card_labels_string]
        cls.label_count = dict((i, card_labels.count(i)) for i in card_labels)

        cards = dict(zip([d['name'] for d in data], [d['shortLink'] for d in data]))
        for key, value in cards.items():
            url_card = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{}/members".format(value)
            res = requests.request(
                "GET",
                url_card,
                params=query
            )
            names = [f['fullName'] for f in res.json()]
            cls.card_m.update({key: names})
            
    @classmethod
    def get_data(cls):
        return cls.label_count, cls.card_m
```

Now we need to run that `startup` method in this class before we start up flask via `app.run`. So it can look something like this...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LabelHelper.startup()
    app.run("your interface", your_port)
```

Now we have populated those static variables with the data. Now you just need to import that static class in whatever file you want and just call `get_data` and you will get what you want. So like this...

```
from labelhelper import LabelHelper

def some_function():
    label_count, card_m = LabelHelper.get_data()
```

FYI in the from import labelhelper being lowercase if cause in general you would name the file containing that class `labelhelper.py`

Comment: Thank you !!!! Sorry, My English is bad. But thankyou very much!

Comment: Your welcome. Good luck with you project. Please mark my answer as accepted so this question can be considered answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "transfer"?  If you want to use them in another function, do this:

```
from main_python import other_function

print(label_count, card_m)
other_function(label_count, card_m)
```

Comment: I mean I want to get card_m and label_count in my app.py which is a flask app and I want to print it or show it on my HTML file .

Comment: I want to use it in another python file